# GUI doesn't work when synchronized method is run

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, synchronize

I have an app with a main object (containing Swing GUI) and a supporting thread which calls on the handle() method of the object.

I noticed that when the handle() method is synchronized, while the thread is using the handle() method, the GUI on the main object are unresponsive. Code:

```
public synchronized void handle()){
//method code
}
```

i remove the synchronized keyword from handle(), the GUI is responsive even when the thread is using the handle() method.

An interesting thing to note is that when I used another object as a lock, the GUI becomes responsive again when the thread is using the handle() method. Code:

```
public void handle(){
    synchronized(anotherObj){
    //method code
    }
}
```

This suggests that Swing GUI uses methods that are synchronized. Am I right? Feel free to point me to any resources - couldn't quite find what I wanted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What is your "handle" method and what does it do? I believe that Swing does not use synchronization for the most part and its documentation in fact states in its API that it is not thread-safe (e.g., have a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)). Instead it uses a single thread for user interactions and program painting, the EDT or *Event Dispatch Thread*, and all programs that interact with Swing must respect this single thread model by calling most all Swing calls on the EDT. I suspect this is where your problem lies.

For more on Swing threading and use of background threads, please have a look here: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

**Edit 1**
(From my comment) I have to ask also, why this method is synchronized? Since we queue all Swing calls onto the event queue, this probably isn't necessary and is possibly harmful. A Swing program freeze almost always is due to a concurrency issue so this discussion is relevant.

You might want to make a small compilable test program (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) that demonstrates your problem (the GUI freeze) and post it here so we can test it for ourselves.

Comment: @Amir: thanks.  Do you mean that you have only 7 more up-votes left?

Comment: Ah i've considered the EDT already. But it doesn't seem to give any insight on why this is so.
The handle basically processes the input and sends back a server response - it has nothing to do with the GUI. But it should not matter what the handle does - the difference is only in the synchronization.

Comment: @worwhite: but it does matter. Are you making Swing calls from within the handle method (likely yes), and are you making sure that it is being called on the EDT?  Also, why is this method synchronized? Since you queue all Swing calls onto the event queue, this probably isn't necessary and is possibly harmful. You might want to make a small compilable program that demonstrates your freeze and post it here so we can test it for ourselves.

Comment: Hmm the handle does at times call another method (not synchronized) that calls textArea.append() and textField.setText(). But in this case using another object as a lock should still cause the freeze right?
The method is synchronized because it is accessed by other threads and might result in interference. This is the server part of a client-server program. It is a bit too complicated to post I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not asking you to post your program, just a small test program that demonstrates the problem. The long-running task can be mimicked by a Thread.sleep(...).

Comment: I know... to convert it into a small program would likewise take up too much time. What I can do for now is to remove all swing calls that are accessed indirectly by handle() and test that.

Comment: @Wor, you need to do two things: first, ensure `handle` isn't called by an event handler, i.e., ensure `handle` is not running on the EDT. Second, place your updates to the UI in a `Runnable` and call them using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: Will do that in a few hours and post results. Thanks.

Comment: @Hovercraft - It was the number of letters I needed to post a comment.

Comment: Ok i did some tests. This is the offending line in handle():
textArea.setCaretPosition(length);
where length is constantly increasing. If length is replaced with a constant (e.g. setCaretPosition(0)) or if this entire line is removed, there is no freeze even when handle() is synchronized. Surprisingly, this line does not cause a freeze if handle() is not synchronized, or if its synchronized with another object (objLock).